# Return values with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I would like to ask you how can I get the values 043, 21.45, 45.65, 9.34, 3.46 with the usage of sscanf.

```
Parameters: 43 VALUES FROM 0000:0000 (043)
Name_8:(Temp=21.45,Hum=45.65,AR=9.34,Volt=3.46V)
```

Until the FROM I know that the code is something like that

```
char str[20];
sscanf(buff,"%*s %*d %*s %s",str);
printf("Results %s\n",str);
```

And this returns me

```
Results FROM
```

But I do not know how to continue with sscanf. I am not very familiar and I do not know how to escape characters like (),_,: etc.

Comment: Have you read the sscanf documentation?

Comment: I tried to understand it from the following source but it has an example for a simple sentence and not like mine http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: Follow the "see also" to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ which has much more information about the format. In particular, "Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format." ... You can use that to skip the constant parts of your input format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parts of the input that don't change can be specified literally, you don't need %*s to skip them. The variant part can be skipped with the %*d and %*s you use. Running this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char buff[] = "Parameters: 43 VALUES FROM 0000:0000 (043)\n"
                  "Name_8:(Temp=21.45,Hum=45.65,AR=9.34,Volt=3.46V)";
    int tag;
    float Temp, Hum, AR, Volt;
    int n;

    n = sscanf (buff, "Parameters: %*d VALUES FROM %*d:%*d (%d) "
                      "Name_%*d:(Temp=%f,Hum=%f,AR=%f,Volt=%fV)",
                       &tag,    &Temp,   &Hum, &AR,  &Volt);
    if (n == 5) {
        printf ("tag = %d, Temp = %f, Hum = %f, AR = %f, Volt = %f\n",
                 tag, Temp, Hum, AR, Volt);
    } else {
        printf ("Couldn't scan all items (converted %d).\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

will output

```
tag = 43, Temp = 21.450001, Hum = 45.650002, AR = 9.340000, Volt = 3.460000
```

**Always check the return value of sscanf!** You don't want to soldier on with garbage values. And note that a single space in the format skips any amount of whitespace, so the space after `)` skips the newline in the input.

Comment: That `if` expression would look much better if you separated the assignment out of it.

Comment: Oh well, it's an idiom I learned from K&R, first edition. Call me old-school :-)

Comment: @Jens: As mentioned above output will be Temp = 21.450001. How can we maintain the precision? so that is outputs only 21.450000.

Answer (score 0):

For first line you can try something like this.But second line could be tricky :)

```
 char f1[] = "Parameters: 43 VALUES FROM 0000:0000 (043)";
 int d = 0;
 sscanf(f1, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s (%d)",&d);
 printf("D %d \n", d);
```

However if you can modify the second like by adding space between numeric values

```
 char f2[] = "Name_8:(Temp= 21.45,Hum= 45.65,AR= 9.34,Volt= 3.46V)";
```

Then you can use this to read float values

```
float te= 0, h = 0, ar = 0, v = 0;
sscanf(f2, "%*s %f%*s %f%*s %f%*s %f)",&te, &h, &ar, &v);
```

Comment: There's not need to change the input format to contain spaces if you adjust the format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char buff[] = "Parameters: 43 VALUES FROM 0000:0000 (043)\n"
                "Name_8:(Temp=21.45,Hum=45.65,AR=9.34,Volt=3.46V)";
    char dev[25], temp[25], hum[25], ar[25], volt[25];
    int pos = 0, len;
    sscanf(buff, "%*[^(](%[^)])%n", dev, &len);
    pos += len;
    sscanf(buff + pos, "%*[^(](Temp=%[^,],%n", temp, &len);
    pos += len;
    sscanf(buff + pos, "Hum=%[^,],%n", hum, &len);
    pos += len;
    sscanf(buff + pos, "AR=%[^,],%n", ar, &len);
    pos += len;
    sscanf(buff + pos, "Volt=%[^V]V%n", volt, &len);
    printf("dev:%s\n", dev);
    printf("temp:%s\n", temp);
    printf("hum:%s\n", hum);
    printf("ar:%s\n", ar);
    printf("volt:%s\n", volt);
    return 0;
}
```